# Getting object disposed exception with sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, object, exception

First of all. I apologize for the massive code snippet. But I am hopeless at this stage, and need some answer to what I am doing wrong.

I start the server, Then the client connects to the server and click sign in to authenticate his password. But the thing is. The first time I send the request, everything works perfectly, but the second time directly after the first attempt, when I press the sign in button again. I get

> Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll

I can't seem to figure out where my problem is.

I also need help to where I must disconnect the user and all that house keeping stuff.

The code :

```
    private byte[] _buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    static List<Socket> _connectedClients = new List<Socket>();
    private Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
    private IPEndPoint ipport = null;
    private int port = 0;


    private void SetupServer()
    {
        lstConnections.Items.Add("--==(  Setting Up Server  )==--");
        _serverSocket.Bind(ipport);
        _serverSocket.Listen(38);
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket;
        try
        {
            //socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {

            return;
        }

        _connectedClients.Add(socket);
        socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), socket);
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lstConnections.Items.Add("Client Connected, Waiting for request..."); });
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
    }

    private void RecieveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int recieved = 0;
            try
            {
                recieved = socket.EndReceive(AR);

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                FileHandlerTxt FHandler = new FileHandlerTxt();
                FHandler.appendDataToTextFile(new List<string> { string.Format("Client forcefully disconnected at {0}. Error : {1}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongDateString(), exc.Message) });
                socket.Close();
                _connectedClients.Remove(socket);
                return;
            }

            byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[recieved];
            Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuffer, recieved);

            object unkown = dataBuffer.Deserialize();

            if (unkown is Login)
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lstConnections.Items.Add("Got login request..."); });
                #region Login
                Login login = (Login)unkown;

                            //Do stuff in the call Class
                            // .Serialize() is an extension method

                            byte[] data = call.Serialize();
                            socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
                            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), socket);
                            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lstConnections.Items.Add(login.Username + " Signed in"); });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageClass call = new MessageClass("Failed. Password incorrect");
                            call.ckey = 2;
                            login.updateFailedAttempts(LoginAttempts + 1);
                            byte[] data = call.Serialize();
                            socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
                            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), socket);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageClass call = new MessageClass("Failed. To many failed attempts");
                        call.ckey = 4;
                        RootObject LocData = LocationData.getLocationData();
                        string message = string.Format("You have entered your password wrong 3 times on {0} at {1} from {2}:{3}. Your account has been locked. Please go to the lodge to unlock your account.", DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongDateString(), DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString(), IPLocation.getIPAddress(), LocData.country);
                        message.SendEmail();
                        byte[] data = call.Serialize();
                        socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
                        socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), socket);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageClass call = new MessageClass("Failed. User does not exists");
                    call.ckey = 3;
                    byte[] data = call.Serialize();
                    socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
                    socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), socket);
                }
                #endregion
            }
            else if (unkown is Client)
            {
                #region Client
                Client newClient = (Client)unkown;
                newClient.Queries(newClient.ckey);
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    lstConnections.Items.Add("Did requested Client query");
                });

                #endregion
            }
            else if (unkown is MessageClass)
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lstConnections.Items.Add("Got Disconnect request..."); });
                MessageClass call = (MessageClass)unkown;
                if (call.ckey == -10)
                {
                    socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    socket.Close();
                    socket.Dispose();
                    _connectedClients.Remove(socket);
                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lstConnections.Items.Add("Client Disconnected..."); });
                    return;
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            FileHandlerTxt FHandler = new FileHandlerTxt();
            FHandler.appendDataToTextFile(new List<string> { string.Format("RecieveCallback problem at {0}. Error : {1}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongDateString(), exc.Message) });
        }


    }



    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        socket.EndSend(AR);
    }
```

Then there is the client side. 
Which again, I hope it's done right :

```
private void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {



        //Enable wat onder is vir Authentication

        try
        {

            Login login = new Login(txtUsername.Text,passboxPassword.SecurePassword.EncryptPassword(txtUsername.Text),IPLocation.getIPAddress(),0);
            _clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.14"),8081));
            _clientSocket.Send(login.Serialize());
            RecieveResponse();
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            FileHandlerTxt FHandler = new FileHandlerTxt();
            FHandler.appendDataToTextFile(new List<string> { string.Format("Socket Exception {0} on {1}", se.Message, DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongDateString()) });
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            FileHandlerTxt FHandler = new FileHandlerTxt();
            FHandler.appendDataToTextFile(new List<string> { string.Format("Exception {0} on {1}", exc.Message, DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongDateString()) });
        }



    }


    private void RecieveResponse()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int recieved = _clientSocket.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
        if (recieved == 0) return;
        byte[] data = new byte[recieved];
        Array.Copy(buffer,data,recieved);
        object unkown = data.Deserialize();
        MessageClass returnMessage = (MessageClass)unkown;
        if (returnMessage.ckey == 1)
        {
            string AskingPasscode = "";
            RecievePasscode passauth = new RecievePasscode();
            if (passauth.ShowDialog() == false)
            {
                AskingPasscode = passauth.PassCode;
            }
            if (AskingPasscode == returnMessage.PassKey.DecryptPasscode(txtUsername.Text))
            {
                if (returnMessage.AuthLevel == 2)
                {
                    SESSION.AccountType = "Admin";
                    SESSION.AuthLevel = 2;
                    SESSION.ID = returnMessage.client.ID;
                    SESSION.Name = returnMessage.client.Name;
                    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
                    main.Show();
                    this.Close();
                }
                else if (returnMessage.AuthLevel == 1)
                {
                    SESSION.AccountType = "Hunter";
                    SESSION.AuthLevel = 1;
                    SESSION.ID = returnMessage.client.ID;
                    SESSION.Name = returnMessage.client.Name;
                    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
                    main.Show();
                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    SESSION.AccountType = "User";
                    SESSION.AuthLevel = 0;
                    SESSION.ID = returnMessage.client.ID;
                    SESSION.Name = returnMessage.client.Name;
                    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
                    main.Show();
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(returnMessage.Message);
        }

        MessageClass call = new MessageClass("Exit");
        call.ckey = -10;
        _clientSocket.Send(call.Serialize());
        _clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        _clientSocket.Close();
        _clientSocket.Dispose();
        MessageBox.Show("Client Disconnect.");


    }
```

Comment: Are you getting this exception on the server side or the client side?

Comment: The program does not break on that problem. But according to my error handeling. It happens on the client side

Comment: And then it happens in the server also.. I call track it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client-side, you are Disposing `_clientSocket` in `RecieveResponse`, but `_clientSocket` seems is reused by the next button click in `btnSignIn_Click`.  This will certainly cause an `ObjectDisposedException`

You will need to create a new socket each time.

Comment: I see. How would I create a new socket each time the button is clicked?   Because When I press the btnSignIn it send the Login Info to be checked by the server. and the send a message back to the client to say that the client should continue or sign in failed.